# Changing the image source using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

My DOM looks like this:

```
<div id="d1">
   <div class="c1">
            <a href="#"><img src="img1_on.gif"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img2_on.gif"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

When someone clicks on an image, I want the image src to change to `<img src="imgx_off.gif">` where `x` represents the image number 1 or 2.

Is this possible or do I have to use CSS to change the images?

Comment: If you want something using jQuery you might want to look into the *[jQuery Cycle Plugin, demo scrollRight](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)* (bottom-right example)

Answer (score 1879):

You can use jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.  For example, if your `img` tag has an `id` attribute of 'my_image', you would do this:

```
<img id="my_image" src="first.jpg" alt="Insert link 1 alt text here" />
```

Then you can change the `src` of your image with jQuery like this:

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");
```

To attach this to a `click` event, you could write:

```
$('#my_image').on({
    'click': function(){
        $('#my_image').attr('src','second.jpg');
    }
});
```

To rotate the image, you could do this:

```
$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img1_on.jpg')
            ? 'img2_on.jpg'
            : 'img1_on.jpg';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 92):

One of the common mistakes people do when change the image source is not waiting for image load to do afterward actions like maturing image size etc.
You will need to use jQuery `.load()` method to do stuff after image load.

```
$('yourimageselector').attr('src', 'newsrc').load(function(){
  $(this).width(); // this is how you get new width of image
});
```

You may need to do `this.width;` instead if your images are in memory; `$(this).width()` will not work there.

Comment: Yes. This finally did the trick. .destroy() doesn't go nearly far enough. Nuking all the html and than init again actually works when swapping out images of various sizes and such.

Comment: note that load won't fire reliably, especially if the image is in the cache. See the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 37):

> In case you update the image multiple times and it gets **CACHED** and
>   does not update, add a random string at the end:

```
// update image in dom
$('#target').attr('src', 'https://example.com/img.jpg?rand=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: It is very important, at least for me, to add the random string at the end! Tanks!

Comment: You can also use the date and time the image was updated as the string, instead of a random string. This would be more efficient for caching, but it's a little more work to track this update time data.

Answer (score 21):

For more information. I try setting src attribute with attr method in jquery for ad image using the syntax for example: `$("#myid").attr('src', '/images/sample.gif');`

This solution is useful and it works but if changing the path change also the path for image and not working.

I've searching for resolve this issue but not found nothing.

The solution is putting the '\' at the beginning the path: 
`$("#myid").attr('src', '\images/sample.gif');`

This trick is very useful for me and I hope it is useful for other.

Answer (score 19):

IF there is not only jQuery or other resource killing frameworks - many kb to download each time by each user just for a simple trick - but also native JavaScript(!):

```
<img src="img1_on.jpg" 
    onclick="this.src=this.src.match(/_on/)?'img1_off.jpg':'img1_on.jpg';">
<img src="img2_on.jpg" 
    onclick="this.src=this.src.match(/_on/)?'img2_off.jpg':'img2_on.jpg';">
```

This can be written general and more elegant:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function switchImg(img){
    img.src = img.src.match(/_on/) ? 
        img.src.replace(/_on/, "_off") : 
        img.src.replace(/_off/, "_on");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img1_on.jpg" onclick="switchImg(this)">
    <img src="img2_on.jpg" onclick="switchImg(this)">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17):

I'll show you how to change the image `src`, so that when you click an image it rotates through all the images that are in your HTML (in your `d1` id and `c1` class specifically)... whether you have 2 **or more images** in your HTML.

I'll also show you how to clean up the page after the document is ready, so that only one image is displayed initially.

**The full code**

```
$(function() {

    var $images = $("#d1 > .c1 > a").clone();  

    var $length = $images.length;
    var $imgShow = 0;

    $("#d1 > .c1").html( $("#d1 > .c1 > a:first") );  

    $("#d1 > .c1 > a").click(function(event) { 

        $(this).children().attr("src", 
                        $("img", $images).eq(++$imgShow % $length).attr("src") );
        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

**The breakdown**

1. Create a copy of the links containing the images (note: you could also make use of the href attribute of the links for added functionality... for example **[display the working link below each image](http://jsfiddle.net/NHASn/)**):

   ```
       var $images = $("#d1 > .c1 > a").clone();  ;
   ```
2. Check how many images were in the HTML and create a variable to track which image is being shown:

   ```
   var $length = $images.length;
   var $imgShow = 0;
   ```
3. Modify the document's HTML so that **only** the first image is being shown. Delete all the other images.

   ```
   $("#d1 > .c1").html( $("#d1 > .c1 > a:first") );
   ```
4. Bind a function to handle when the image link is clicked.

   ```
       $("#d1 > .c1 > a").click(function(event) { 
           $(this).children().attr("src", $("img", $images).eq(++$imgShow % $length).attr("src") );
           event.preventDefault();
       });
   ```

   The heart of the above code is using `++$imgShow % $length` to cycle through the jQuery object containing the images. `++$imgShow % $length` first increases our counter by one, then it mods that number with how many images there are. This will keep the resultant index cycling from `0` to `length-1`, which are the indices of the `$images` object. This means this code will work with 2, 3, 5, 10, or 100 images... cycling through each image in order and restarting at the first image when the last image is reached.

   Additionally, **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** is used to get and set the "src" attribute of the images. To pick elements from among the `$images` object, I set `$images` as the **[jQuery context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** using the form `$(selector, context)`. Then I use **[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to pick just the element with the specific index I'm interested in.

---

### **[jsFiddle example with 3 images](http://jsfiddle.net/YXXHy/)**

You can also store the `src`s in an array.
**[jsFiddle example with 3 images](http://jsfiddle.net/wjapW/)**

And here's how to incorporate the hrefs from the anchor tags around the images:
**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRTDS/)**

Answer (score 17):

Hope this can work

```
<img id="dummyimage" src="http://dummyimage.com/450x255/" alt="" />
<button id="changeSize">Change Size</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flag = 0;
    $("button#changeSize").click(function() {
        if (flag == 0) {
            $("#dummyimage").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/250x155/");
            flag = 1;
        } else if (flag == 1) {
            $("#dummyimage").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/450x255/");
            flag = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

You should add id attribute to your image tag, like this:

```
<div id="d1">
   <div class="c1">
            <a href="#"><img id="img1" src="img1_on.gif"></a>
            <a href="#"><img id="img2" src="img2_on.gif"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

then you can use this code to change the source of images:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#img1").attr({ "src": "logo-ex-7.png" });
        $("#img2").attr({ "src": "logo-ex-8.png" });
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this with jQuery in this way:

```
$(".c1 img").click(function(){
     $(this).attr('src','/new/image/src.jpg');   
});
```

You can have a condition if there are multiple states for the image source.

Comment: this syntax is not right.  the jquery attr() function takes 1 or 2 params.  The first being a string with the HTML attribute name, the second being the value for that attribute that you want to set.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when trying to call re captcha button.
After some searching, now  the below function works fine in almost all the famous browsers(chrome,Firefox,IE,Edge,...):

```
function recaptcha(theUrl) {
  $.get(theUrl, function(data, status){});
  $("#captcha-img").attr('src', "");
  setTimeout(function(){
       $("#captcha-img").attr('src', "captcha?"+new Date().getTime());
  }, 0);
 }
```

'theUrl' is used to render new captcha image and can be ignored in your case. The most important point is generating new URL which forces FF and IE to rerender the image.

Answer (score 7):

Change the image source using jQuery `click()`

element:

```
    <img class="letstalk btn"  src="images/chatbuble.png" />
```

code:

```
    $(".letstalk").click(function(){
        var newsrc;
        if($(this).attr("src")=="/images/chatbuble.png")
        {
            newsrc="/images/closechat.png";
            $(this).attr("src", newsrc);
        }
        else
        {
            newsrc="/images/chatbuble.png";
            $(this).attr("src", newsrc);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a codepen with exactly this functionality here. I will give you a breakdown of the code here as well.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Neil_Meyer_ZA/pen/PoGQGRa)

```js
$(function() {

  //Listen for a click on the girl button
  $('#girl-btn').click(function() {

    // When the girl button has been clicked, change the source of the #square image to be the girl PNG
    $('#square').prop("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png");
  });

  //Listen for a click on the plane button
  $('#plane-btn').click(function() {

    // When the plane button has been clicked, change the source of the #square image to be the plane PNG
    $('#square').prop("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
  });

  //Listen for a click on the fruit button
  $('#fruits-btn').click(function() {

    // When the fruits button has been clicked, change the source of the #square image to be the fruits PNG
    $('#square').prop("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png" id="square" />
<div>
  <button id="girl-btn">Girl</button>
  <button id="plane-btn">Plane</button>
  <button id="fruits-btn">Fruits</button>

  <a href="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/">Source of Images</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same wonder today, I did on this way :

```
//<img src="actual.png" alt="myImage" class=myClass>
$('.myClass').attr('src','').promise().done(function() {
$(this).attr('src','img/new.png');  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a guaranteed way to get it done in Vanilla (or simply Pure) JavaScript:

```
var picurl = 'pictures/apple.png';
document.getElementById("image_id").src=picurl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition, to make it even more tiny:

```
$('#imgId').click(function(){
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr('src') == 'img1_on.gif' ? 'img1_off.gif':'img1_on.gif');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short but exact

```
$("#d1 img").click(e=> e.target.src= pic[e.target.src.match(pic[0]) ? 1:0] );
```

```js
let pic=[
  "https://picsum.photos/id/237/40/40", // arbitrary - eg: "img1_on.gif",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/238/40/40", // arbitrary - eg: "img2_on.gif"
];

$("#d1 img").click(e=> e.target.src= pic[e.target.src.match(pic[0]) ? 1:0] );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1">
   <div class="c1">
            <a href="#"><img src="img1_on.gif"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img2_on.gif"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of changing the image source with CSS.

Only possible way is using [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) or any [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

### Logic-

The images are inside a div and there are no `class` or `id` with that image.

So logic will be select the elements inside the `div` where the images are located.

Then select all the images elements with loop and change the image src with [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) / [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

### Example Code with demo output-

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
      $("#d1 .c1 a").each(function()
      {
          $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e56672acdbce5d9eda58a178ade59ffe');
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1">
   <div class="c1">
            <a href="#"><img src="img1_on.gif"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img2_on.gif"></a>
   </div>
</div>

<button>Change The Images</button>
```