# How do I make an image change when the mouse is over it HTML?

Tags: html

How do I make an image change when the mouse is over it?

Snippet:

```
<body>

<!-- Site navigation menu -->
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><img src="C:\Users\Drew French\Pictures\Style\SepiaWeb\button_demo5.png" alt="Button 1" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could use jQuery;

```
$("#ImageID").hover( function() { $(this).attr("src", "new src"); } );
```

Also check this out [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-img-src-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS or Javascript for this.

http://joemaller.com/js-singleroll.shtml