# how to use pyquery to modify a node attribute in python

Tags: python, pyquery

iwant use pyquery to do this.

for example:

```
html='<div>arya stark<img src="1111"/>ahahah<img src="2222"/></div>'
a=PyQuery(html)
```

i want to modify  the html to

```
<div>arya stark<img src="aaaa"/>ahahah<img src="bbbb"/></div>
```

in other words,
just need  change img element's  src attribute, and get the modified html.

any ideas?or any other method?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PyQuery is meant you mirror jQuery, perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-img-src-using-jquery) would be relevant. Long story short, use the [`attr()`](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/attributes.html) method:

```
>>> html='<div>arya stark<img src="1111"/>ahahah<img src="2222"/></div>'
>>> a=PyQuery(html)
>>> a.outerHtml()
'<div>arya stark<img src="1111">ahahah<img src="2222"></div>'
>>> for img in a('img'):
...     PyQuery(img).attr('src', "whatever")
...
[<img>]
[<img>]
>>> a.outerHtml()
'<div>arya stark<img src="whatever">ahahah<img src="whatever"></div>'
```

Comment: yes ,but selector(img) return a img list, i want to get the modified full html.thanks

Comment: I added a code snippet. To get the wrapping HTML back out, use the [`outerHtml()`](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html#pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery.outerHtml) method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import pyquery

html = '<div>arya stark<img src="1111"/>ahahah<img src="2222"/></div>'
tree = pyquery.PyQuery(html)
tree('img:first').attr('src', 'cccc')
print str(tree)

<div>arya stark<img src="cccc"/>ahahah<img src="2222"/></div>
```

To apply a function to a selection you can use **.each()**, but note that bare elements are passed to the function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> tree('img').each(lambda i, n: print(n.attrib))
{'src': 'cccc'}
{'src': '2222'}
```