# HTML Element Refresh

Tags: android, html, image

Hey guys, new to HTML, can't find a simple solution anywhere.
I am writing an app for android that "streams" video by taking photos at a small set interval. The idea is to stream this to a website, my problem is that I can't find a simple, small way to refresh just the image on the website (yes, I'm coding the website too).

Any pointers would be great, I'm not looking for a complete worked solution, just some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `src` attribute of the current image to the new image using `javascript`

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "newimagedir.jpg";    
image.onload = function(){
    //when it loads
    document.getElementById("myImage").src= image.src;
}

<img src="" id="myImage" />
```

If you are going to be doing a lot of HTML manipulation i suggest you use a javascript library. If so you can see how to change the image here: [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-img-src-using-jquery)