# Change of Picture through Toggle event

Tags: jquery

I have two pictures. one `arrow_right.png` and `arrow_left.png`. I want to display Only one picture. If Clicked then Toggles to another picture. Can you please help me how to it with jQuery `toggle()` function. Because it is hiding my picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img').toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'arrow_left.png');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'arrow_right.png');
    }
);
```

Docs for `.toggle()`: http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/

### Update

You can also animate the change between each image by using `.animate()` or some of the pre-build animations:

```
$('img').toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-mosaic-image.jpg').fadeTo(250, 1);
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg').fadeTo(250, 1)
        });
    }
);
```

Notice that I used the callback function for `fadeTo` to change the source only after the image has faded-out completely.

Here is a demo (fade): http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/1/

Here is a demo (slide): http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/2/