# Changing image source of list of image tags and replacing it with specific list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace a list of image src in a div tag.
For instance :

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->  
<div id="Listofimages">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
</div>
```

So here i want to change these 3 image source.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have followed this so i know how to change the image source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: Where's the code you've got so far? Why is it not in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ac52D/

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Little explanation:

below code takes all the `img` tag inside `div` with id `Listofimages` and changes its img src.

The demo contains before and after alerts.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
var src = "google.com";
$('#Listofimages img').each(function(){
         alert("IMG Source before change => " + $(this).prop('src'));
         $(this).prop('src', src);
        alert("IMG Source After change => " + $(this).prop('src'));
    }
);​
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="Listofimages">
     <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg"/>
     <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg"/>
     <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

​

Comment: I would hope you would show how to cache repetitively-accessed jQuery object selectors like `$(this)`. I would also demonstrate using `console.log(this)` instead of `alert(what you have)`, and use `var $imgs = $('#Listofimages img');` just so it was easier to read. It's very messy. Also, keep in mind that `this.src` is available, so `$.prop()` may not be necessary just to access the current value.

Comment: Never did jquery before and wanted a quick solution for it cause of time crunch situation here. I will apply this in my code and let see if the magic happens to wot i want to do with all the images. Thanks for the start.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Howz it going bruv! :) yep cheers for the addition, can do the improvements +1 for the suggestions/ideas Jared. OP (@Rahul) please read Jared's comment as well) thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$('#Listofimages img').eq(0).attr('src', 'new_image_1');
$('#Listofimages img').eq(1).attr('src', 'new_image_2');
$('#Listofimages img').eq(2).attr('src', 'new_image_3');
```

Comment: Please God for all that is great and good in the world do not tell anyone to do that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish why? Besides the lack of selectors caching and loops, this is a very suitable and fully working answer to OP's "question".

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Because running that THREE TIMES is completely unnecessary, simply to access `$.eq()` three different times? No, absolutely not.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Unfortunately to modify 3 elements you must access them 3 times, whether it's manually or with a loop. Either way makes no difference.

Comment: Nope. I've got a fiddle going to demonstrate a more direct approach.

Comment: I'd go with a loop if there were too many elements to access as well, but manually changing each of them may provide more control/readability. The only issue I see is running the selector 3 times, storing it like `$imgs = $('#Listofimages img');` then extracting its `eq`s would provide a little performance boost and readability as well, not that it really matters.

Comment: Right here: http://jsfiddle.net/SYXBg/

Comment: Yeah... That's a loop accessing an element an element three times. Just like I said. :)

Comment: @FabricioMatte - In an environment where we are trying to show people, especially beginners, what to do, a pattern like this reinforces that the concept that requerying over and over is alright, just y'know, as long as it's not too many. How many? Who knows. Just demonstrate doing it as right as possible, not something that is too easily interpreted as right but isn't a good practice to be establishing. The iterator approach is not hard or difficult to get right, and is probably half as much typing as this example.

Comment: @JaredFarrish There's nothing wrong with this example other than what you've blown it up to be with your inadequate and confusing jsfiddle example which doesn't even address the original posters' question. Thanks though.

Comment: Lol guys calm down ffs. @JaredFarrish I understand your points perfectly fine. Nevertheless, in OP's "question" (there isn't even a single question mark to call it a question!) it's really hard to say what he wants. Does he wants to replace all `img`s in the same function? If so, iteration is fine and can be enforced. But honestly, there's no question to stress over.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - No worries, these types of arguments often come down to competing points of view strongly held. [On principle](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/), we don't agree; that's fine. Who knows what the OP was after; that had a lot to do with why I chose not to provide an answer, even at this point. There's just not a lot of utility to this whole question, but oh well.

Comment: I see. I do use loops for basically everything and hardly ever repeat a single line of code unless strictly necessary, as I stick to the DRY principle in order to make the code more maintainable. However, when someone else decides to use `eq`, that is, for a 2-3 elements set and would also add/modify specific properties to each (which would require conditionals if inside a loop), then I can see their points as well. Then again, OP didn't specify anything in his question. Also, @JaredFarrish, little correction, Norse only repeated 54/56 characters per line instead of 55. `:)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Read that article I linked to. And I noticed I was one off. The point still stands, nine of ten developers would see that they wrote that and want to refactor. Is it "more better" to do so? Yes, but most developers become sticklers for these things over time. It's part of how you develop an eye to spot problems before they occur and make corrections when it's hopefully optimal, not after the code was delivered to the client and hey, something like this is here, there, and it causes your script to run so poorly people lose work. It can happen. See my `$(this)` question I asked.

Comment: And I'll apologize, Norse, I shouldn't have been flippant. I was being serious enough in my intent and that code (in my opinion) is a perfect question in class for *how could this be refactored?". Y'know, I see a lot of what I consider "off" code around here, see my comments on one of the other answers on this question, and occasionally I learn something I didn't know before being loud. So, no hard feelings, I got a little involved.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Weirdly enough, I've read your `$(this)` question earlier today. Just this week I started enforcing my selectors caching as well. Also, your linked article was a nice read (even though I'm not much familiar with python). I see what you mean, people usually go with "as long as it works, it's fine", so they end up getting used to writing [WET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#Violating_DRY) code and it's a bad practice which isn't easy to get rid of, so I understand your points as well.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - That was a hard-won epiphany. Requerying is especially detrimental in situations that are highly time-sensitive, such as animation. It wasn't until I figured it out a few months *later* that doing that could... be a big part of the problem. By then it was too late. So. Nowadays I think jQuery does some selector caching internally, so this particular piece of code may or may not cause excessive and unnecessary DOM requests, but if it is... Anyhow, we all gotta learn what our approach is in practice. You can only warn others so much. Hard lessons seem to lead to  good ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like following:

***Your HTML***

```
<div id="Listofimages">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
    <img src="images\2page_img_3.jpg">
</div>
```

***jQuery code***

```
var url = 'http://assets.techdreams.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/GoogleChromeLogo1.png';
$('#Listofimages img').prop('src', function(index, oldSource) {
    return url;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ac52D/4/)**

[**`.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop) accepts second parameter as function and parameter of that function is `index` and `oldValue` respectively.

Comment: I'm going to [attach this for posterity](http://jsfiddle.net/SYXBg/) as a comment here; I don't really feel like posting it as an answer. My approach was an `$.each()` using `this.src`. Something that's interesting to compare both approaches, I think. I forget about the `$.prop()` interator method most of the time as it is.