# How right add image in div?

Tags: jquery, image

Good day

Script:

```
var img_src="../Images/" + data;
$("#div_yui_img").html(\'<img src="img_src" id="yui_img" height="100" width="100">\');
```

but after add in html i see:

```
<div id="div_yui_img"><img src="img_src" id="yui_img" height="100" width="100"></div>
```

tell me please how right add image in div, that get(example):

```
<div id="div_yui_img"><img src="../Images/test.jpg" id="yui_img" height="100" width="100"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/554289/1083581

Comment: @happybuddha please see question first. link not have answer on MY question. i ask other question.

Comment: I read your question darn well. You are trying to update the src of an img tag and are able to fetch the variables name instead of its value. If you read through the link that I provided, you will find your answer.

Comment: @happybuddha i dont see. show me please when you see answer on my questuion?

Comment: Whatever makes the function call, I think this should serve your purpose. > $('yui_img').attr('src','../Images/test.jpg');

Comment: @happybuddha do you think that you say? see my question! i dont ask "how change img attribute". i ask how past image in div. These are very different questions. if you see answer on **my** question on your page give me screenshot because i don't see answers on my question on your page.

Comment: If I have understood you incorrectly, and with what you are trying to communicate, I am afraid, I don't understand what your question is. Good luck

Comment: @happybuddha if you understand need ask! Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method :

```
var img_src="../Images/" + data;
$("#div_yui_img").html('<img src="'+img_src+'" id="yui_img" height="100" width="100">');
```