# How to change image src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="branding">
<h1 class="logo">
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/" class="logo">
<img src="http://www.whatever.com/test.png"></a>
</h1>
</div>
```

I am trying to access the image src with the following to no avail:

```
$("a.logo img").html("<img src='http://www.whatever.com/newimage.png'>");
```

The reason I am doing this is because the image is on a third party that I can't access the codebase to make the change so I am trying to rip out their  with my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: don't you google first ??

Answer (score 3):

src is attribute. You should use `.attr()` to get/set attribute values using jquery:

```
 $("a.logo img").attr("src","http://www.whatever.com/newimage.png");
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I didn't realize that the src was an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

.html() changes the html CONTENT of a node, e.g.

```
orig: <p>foo</p>
$('p').html('bar');
neW: <p>bar</p>
```

An `<img>` has NO content. Try

```
$('p.logo img').attr('src', 'new url here');
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
img.attr('src','http://mynewsource.com');
```

Comment: Thank you but it appears that this only works on the latest jQuery.  The version I am relegated on using is jquery-1.7.2.min.js which does update the image but then some of the other jQuery elements on page no longer work. Strange.

Comment: well ok ,if you want more help on this give some more details in your question.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out the answer:

```
$('a.logo img').attr("src", "http://www.whatever.com/newimage.png" );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this exactly what @milinaanantwar wrote?