# Change slider images src using jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code of slider

```
 <div class="jcarousel">
   <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_hot_deal2.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images
      /Banner_free_delivery_extend_west.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_nationwide_delivery.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_merries.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_sep_promo.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_aimedia.jpg"></li>   
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_diapers.jpg"></li>      
      <li><img src="/c.3713628_SB2/site/Images/banner_water.jpg"></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I want to change each and every img src of this slider when the value is selected from drop down is ja_JP which is Japanese language.I need to upload images which is having Japanese text if someone select the Japanese language.

Here is my code which is giving me the value of selected option

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var e = document.getElementById("shopperlanguage"); 
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 if(strUser=="ja_JP"){

<!-- here i need to add code to change each and every img src with different src -->
  }

</script>
```

I know one solution to assign different id to img but is there any other solution to check image and assign different src.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1xDuvNh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myJapaneseImgSrcs=['http://example.com/j1.png','http://example.com/j2.png',...];

$(".jcarousel img").each(function(index,ele){
   $(this).attr('src',myJapaneseImgSrcs[index]);
});
```

Not tested.

Docs - http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: i want to replace with different src for different img