# Custom toggle function in AJAX success code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have one img div. Onclick on it, AJAx inserts into database smthng. I want to change img add.png to added.png on click.

```
First click: add.png -> added.png
Next click: added.png -> add.png etc.
```

I try:

```
success: function(){
    $('.paste_here').html("<img src=\"add.png\">");
}
```

So, how can I do to change the add to added and added to add on each click in success part???

Comment: The sample given here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery
does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: define a flag

```
var flag=true;
```

2: check for flag and then decide what to call(add.png or added.png).

```
success: function(){
 if(flag){
      $('.paste_here').html("<img src=\"added.png\">");
      flag=false
        }
 else{
     $('.paste_here').html("<img src=\"add.png\">");
     flag=true
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not me. I upvote it. But do not accept yet. I will try it later when I can

Answer (score 0):

Will using this work?

```
success: function(){
    $('.paste_here').html("<img src=\"added.png\">");
}
```