# How to set up arrow keys to navigate through <img> tags in order?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a "photo gallery" set up on my page where it displays a bunch of thumbnails along the bottom and the user can click an image to view it in the main display.

The top/big image is set like this:

```
<img src="" height="468px" name="frame1" id="picframe"/>
```

It has no src to start out with, which is fine because it gets overwritten quickly, because I've set up an onclick parameter in the  tag for each thumbnail:

```
<img onclick="document.images['frame1'].src='[//image source]'" src="[//image source]" height="70px" />
```

So basically, if the user clicks on the thumbnail, it will overwrite "frame1" and display the image there too.

This works great, but this only works by having the user click - I'd like to set it up so that they can also use the arrow keys - so then they don't have to click on every single thumbnail.

This is where I'm stuck. What would I need to include to set up some way to change the display when an arrow key has been pressed? I've found some code that allows me to check if the left or right arrow has been pressed, but I don't know how to tie that into changing the src for frame1, or how to know which image is "next".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add an `onkeypress` event handler on the `body` tag.

Declare a global variable to remember the image you are currently showing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with jQuery. In arrows add something like `id='showPrev'` and `id='showNext'` so You know which one is pressed.

Mark img with id's `frame-1, frame-2, so on`

Then, on arrow being pressed you can target certain img http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ like `$( "[img:id='frame-#']" )`

Src can be changed as following: refer: [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery) for switching between images, if u need this

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");
```

You just have do decide and find a way, how exacly You want to identify images `[img:id='frame-#']` (change # to actual number)