# How I can update (replace) SRC of existing image based on form parameters when click submit with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form, and I need update SRC on existing image when user click on SUBMIT...

see my front. http://gustavomarques.com.br/INMET/commet/
this images need change after click on submit based on selects fill.

The URL need change some attributes... Example..

AAA and BBB will change based on value of inputs...

```
<form>
    <select name="PARAM1">
        <option value="AAA">
        <option value="BBB">
        <option value="CCC">
    </select>

    <select name="PARAM2">
        <option value="111">
        <option value="222">
        <option value="333">
    </select>
</form>
```

after user clicks on submit the url need update for example  based on selects fills

this img is placed in same document, but outside of form...

thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected change to the image src URL based on the select value?