# How do I change a button into an image on click?

Tags: javascript

Below is my existing code. It successfully changes an image into another image when clicked. I need to change it so it starts off as a button that says "HINT?" on it then changes to an image. I don't wish to use an image as the button.

```
<!--HINT 1-->
<script lanuage="javascript">
  function handleClick1(element) {
      element.src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/dirty.jpg";
  }
</script>
<!--HINT 1 END-->

<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png" onclick="handleClick1(this);">
```

I thought I might be able to change it to a button like so, but it stops it working:

```
<input type="button" value="Hint?" onclick="handleClick1(this);">
```

Comment: because `input type="button"` doesn't support `src`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting with a hidden image (`style="display:none"`), and then using jquery to `show()` the image and `hide()` the button onclick.

you can use an ID on the image along with jquery selectors, instead of having to pass `this` into your function.

also, you can change the `src` of an image using jquery ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)). another option is using the `append` method to append html.

Comment: extra tip: include more relevant tags in your question for more relevant attention (i.e. "html", "javascript", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your original code uses the line:

```
<img onclick="handleClick1(this);">
```

As such, your code is effectively trying to call

```
button.src="http://example.com/myimage.png";
```

Which will not work as the src attribute will only work with an image element.

The easiest way to get the effect that you desire would be to place the elements in a container, then control via CSS whether it should be visible or not. Something like this should solve your problem:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hint">
    <button type="button">Hint?</button>
    <img src="http://example.com/my_ending_image.png">
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function buttonClick(){
    this.parentNode.classList.add("show");
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".hint button");
for (var x=0; x<buttons.length; x++) {
    buttons[x].addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hint.show button {
  display: none;
}

.hint img {
  display: none;
}

.hint.show img {
  display: block;
}
```

A JSFiddle showing the functionality can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get this to work. And I'm not sure why the code you've given references 2 images. Starting and Ending. I only want a button to start with that turns into an image when clicked.

Comment: I misunderstood your question a little, I've changed my answer to hopefully be more in line with what you're after

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I actually figured out how to do it like this:

```
<body onload="hideallhints()">


<script>
function hideallhints() {
    document.getElementById("artwork1").style.display = "none"; 
}

function HINT1() {
    document.getElementById("artwork1").style.display = "block"; 
    document.getElementById("hintbutton").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<img id="artwork1" src="w3javascript.gif" width="100" height="132">
<br>

<button type="button" id="hintbutton" onclick="HINT1()">Hint?</button>



</body>
```