# Replace image by javascript

Tags: image, replace

I want to replace the gif file by javascript. I find the method below. Is there any way i can place the javascript tag before the img tag?

```
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">

<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("myImg")[0].src = "hackanm.gif";
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to?  You *can* place the code wherever you want.  You just need to ensure that the line of code looking for the HTML element doesn't execute until that element exists.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  How does this not work?

Comment: Surround your current javascript with `$( document ).ready(function() {});` (see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ ) and then you can place it anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 3):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." Using jquery's `$(document).ready()`, it Will wait until the page is loaded and ready to be manipulated before executing (no matter where it is on the page). Example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("myImg")[0].src = "hackanm.gif";
    });
</script>
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
```

You could also then leverage selectors inside jquery (e.g. `$(".class")` where class is your class, or `$("#id")` where id is the id) and change the code to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".myImg").attr('src',"hackanm.gif");
    });
</script>
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
```

And further you could even store it in a variable if you wanted to change it later on in javascript as well!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myImg = $(".myImg");
        var newImg = "hackanm.gif";
        myImg.attr('src', newImg);
    });
</script>
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
```

Hope this helps you learn a few new tricks inside javascript! Happy coding!

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP's main concern was flash of the old image before it is replaced by JavaScript. I suggest you add a line of CSS to make your image element visibly hidden then do the swap + unhide with JavaScript.

```
<style>
    .myImg {visibility: hidden;}
</style>

<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">

<script>
    var imgReplace = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg")[0];
    imgReplace.src = "hackanm.gif";
    imgReplace.style.visibility = "visible";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="album_pic">
   <img src="/Images/logo.jpg" id="track_art" alt="cover image" />    </div>
```

```js
 let DIV = document.createElement('div');
        DIV.classList.add('album_pic');       
        DIV.innerHTML = `<img src="${PlayList[songIndex].album_pic}" class="track_art" alt="cover image">`;

        let Cover_image = document.querySelector('.album_pic');
        Cover_image.replaceWith(DIV);
```

In place of "PlayList[songIndex].album_pic" , add your own path.
This is my research and I don't copied from anyone. Also this is all based on what I learned in javascript