# Replace img path jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to replace an img path in jquery (injecting into a remote page)

**replace**
example.com/**thumbs**

**with**
example.com/**images**

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 $("img").attr("src").replace("thumbs", "images");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

This *gets* the value, but doesn't *set* it back to the attribute:

```
$("img").attr("src").replace("thumbs", "images");
```

That requires another step, something like:

```
var newSrc = $("img").attr("src").replace("thumbs", "images");
$("img").attr("src", newSrc);
```

Or, if you want a single line:

```
$("img").attr("src", $("img").attr("src").replace("thumbs", "images"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one, you wasn't setting src for an image.

```js
$(function() {
      $('img').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs', 'imagessss')); console.log('New src: ' + $(this).attr('src'));
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/images/thumbs.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldSrc = 'http://example.com/smith.gif';
var newSrc = 'http://example.com/johnson.gif';
$('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', newSrc);
```

This is what you wanna do:

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the attribute with the returned value for that you can use a callback function as the second argument in [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method where the second argument holds the current attribute value.

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src){ 
   return src.replace('thumbs', 'images'); 
});
```

The above method will iterate over the `img` tags if there are multiple `img` elements so you can avoid using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method for iterating.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('thumbs', 'images');
  });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs1" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs2" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs3" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs4" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs5" alt="#" />
<img src="http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=thumbs6" alt="#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
 var newPath = $("img").attr("src").replace("thumbs", "images");
  $("img").attr("src",newPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">

Step 2:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('img').each(function() {
               $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs', 'images')); 
               console.log('Latest image link ' + $(this).attr('src'));
           });
      });
```