# Ajax img request end with success but cannot set image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, image

I have a default image which is loaded in the HTML. 
Then i check if a personal image exists with an ajax request,
the request is succesful however it cannot set the new image src.
The image loaded from HTML is always displayed.
The code to set the new image src works if it is outside the ajax request.
This is my code:

```
 <img id="imageid" src="media/default/slider.jpg" alt=""/>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">





$.ajax({
    url:'media/' + loginmail + '/slider.jpg',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: "image/gif",
    error: function()
    {


    },
    success: function(data)
    {

        alert("success" );

        $('#imageid').attr('src', "media/" + loginmail +    "/slider.jpg");           
    }
});
```

Thank you.
EDITED:

I really do not know if it changes something but i am using the http://slimimagecropper.com/ Plugin.

```
 <div id="my-cropper" class="slim" style="width:1200px; height: 300px; border:0;"
data-service="async.php"
data-fetcher="fetch.php"
data-ratio="12:3"
data-size="1200,300"
data-label="Insert here your image">   
<img id="imageid" src="media/default/slider.jpg" alt=""/>
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" name="slim[]"/>
```

Comment: what does `data` look like?

Comment: The success function tries to set the image src twice, both with different values.  Until you resolve or clarify that then it'll just be best guesses.

Comment: thank you, sorry, i left some tests, i have corrected my code.

Comment: are you trying to store image path in database.in simple? and what type of development i mean is it asp.net ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38478160/6003350

Comment: no, i used ajax only to see if the image exists. The image is a file on server, not in the DB.

Comment: oh so you are answered? like you dont want to do anything with the image from the server?

Comment: Yes, if the image exists I want to set it as the src.

Comment: have you logged the `data` you got in response in the console? if yes, what it is?

Comment: yes, i did, i have got random symbols 'cause it is an image file. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I replace the image source in ajax with random image url and it works. check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/27hh1syo)

Also write all your inside this function.

```
$(function(){});
```

Comment: thank you, i tried replacing with http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text/.
It doesn't work.

Comment: replace it where you're setting the `src` of image i.e. `$('#imageid').attr('src', "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text/"); `

Comment: thank you, it works on fiddle, i am thinking the problem is the plugin http://slimimagecropper.com/ that i use.

Answer (score 0):

remove below line of code

```
dataType: "image/gif",
```