# how to display images in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

---

Im New to Jquery and Js. I need Help Here. I would like to display Images Onclick Instead Of Text

```
echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="'.$id_post.'" title="Unlike"><img  src="images/fav1.png" width="32"height="32"></a>';
             }else {
       echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="'.$id_post.'" title="Like"><img  src="images/fav.jpg"width="32"height="32"></a>';
   }
```

---

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
              if($(this).attr('title') == 'Like'){
                  $that = $(this);
                  $.post('action.php', {pid:$(this).attr('id'), action:'like'},function(){
                      $that.text('Unlike');
                      $that.attr('title','Unlike');
                  });
              }else{
                  if($(this).attr('title') == 'Unlike'){
                      $that = $(this);
                      $.post('action.php', {pid:$(this).attr('id'), action:'unlike'},function(){
                          $that.text('Like');
                          $that.attr('title','Like');
                      });
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

---

please Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `img` src on click just the way you did with text.

```
if($(this).attr('title') == 'Like') {
  $that.find("img").attr("src","images/fav1.png");
}
else if ($(this).attr('title') == 'Like') {
  $that.find("img").attr("src","images/fav.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Happy to help.!