# How to change src of img loaded by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery load() method to load various elements from webpage in another domain. The script is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#a1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_a1");
        $("#img1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_img1");
        $("#span1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_span1");
    });
</script>
```

and HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="span1"></div>
```

so the result HTML is

```
<div id="a1">
    <a id="another_a1" href="a_relative_url.aspx">description</a>
</div>
<div id="img1">
    <img id="another_img1" src="img_relative_url.ashx">
</div>
<div id="span1">
    <span id="another_span1">content</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the loaded a and img elements has relative urls so hyperlinks don't work properly and images don't show up. How can I fix this?

---

**Edit:**
With your answers the problem is solved and the script is now as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#a1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_a1"function(){
            $("#another_a1").attr("href",function(){
                return "http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/"+$("#another_a1").attr("href");
            });
        });
        $("#img1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_img1",function(){
            $("#another_img1").attr("src",function(){
                return "http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/"+$("#another_img1").attr("src");
            });
        });
        $("#span1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_span1");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "Don't work properly". Well, what do you they do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the content of the element once it has been loaded using a callback function passed to `load`.

```
$("#span1").load("http://webpage.anotherdomain.com/ #another_span1",function(content) {
   //load was successful,
   //in this callback function, you can now access $('#span1').html() and modify it as you see fit.

   //do something to modify the content
   content = content.replace(...)

   //reset the content
   $('#span1').html(content);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any control over the page you are loading, it may be a better idea to not include it on your webpage.

If you still want to do that you can use jQuery's `attr()` function (http://api.jquery.com/attr/). `$("#another_img1").attr("src", [yourUrl]);`