# Display different image on scroll in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the image displayed in navbar (under img src=) when scrolled down. However, the image isn't in a css class so I'm not sure how it could be done. Could you advise the best way to solve this? Should I put the image in a css class?

```html
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/blacklogo.png" width="13% style="padding-top:5px" style="padding-top:0px"  >
```

Comment: you can change img src. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the DOM object of the `img` element and changes the `src` property to update the image.

```js
( function ( win, doc, undefined ) {

  var imgEl    = document.querySelector( '#header-img' ),
      nextSrc  = 'http://placehold.it/1200x100/',
      switched = false;

  function onScroll( e ) {

    imgEl.src = nextSrc;
    win.removeEventListener( 'scroll', onScroll );

  }

  win.addEventListener( 'scroll', onScroll );
  
}( window, window.document ) );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 125vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="header-img" src="http://placehold.it/1200x100/fc0">
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked but there's a bug - imgEl isn't defined within the onScroll function.

Comment: You must not have implemented like I did above. `imgEl` is defined outside of the definition of `onScroll` so `imgEl` is available inside of `onScroll`.

Comment: Hmm yeah I might have made a mistake