# Ajax - delay showing image until downloaded

Tags: php, ajax, image, delay

I'm using the following script to load some articles into a div, these articles contain images. is it possible to only show the image once it has fully downloaded rather than rendering it bit by bit?

```
<script>
$("#getnews").click(function(){ 
$("#nhsnews").load("news_feed.php");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could set src after img loaded

Comment: how would go about doing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery