# Changing the folder path context inside the view to root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 with .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I'm using an external library to create a chart. The html references a dynamically created image,

`<img usemap="#MainContent_C1WebChart1_MAP" id="MainContent_C1WebChart1" src="chartimage.aspx?SessionID=FooBar&amp;Delete=T">`

But it's looking at `/Home/chartimage.aspx?SessionID=FooBar&amp;Delete=T` (which returns file not found)

It currently exists under `/chartimage.aspx?SessionID=FooBar&amp;Delete=T`

What would be the best way to fix this pathing error? I cannot change the src attribute in the img to include a '/' prior to run time it as this is generated by an external library.

**Controller:** /Controllers/HomeController

**View:** /Views/Home/Sitemaster and /Views/Home/Default.aspx.

If I make this view the default startup page it works.
**RouteConfig:**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        //localhost:9000 Works great! But I don't want this as the default page.
        //localhost:9000/Home/Index Doesn't work :( It's trying to get the resource from /Home/chartimage.aspx...
```

Comment: you can change the src value using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)  on how to change the `src` value of an image.

If you want to use Rewrite URL:

```
   <rule name="Remove en" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/Home$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

if your example is `www.local.com/home/chartimage.aspx` will be rewritten as

```
www.local.com/chartimage.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks for the link Ishida! I was thinking of that; would this be good practice? Or would remapping the routes on the server side be a better option

Comment: I would say handle it using jquery, instead of handling it through routes. Other way is to write a rewrite rule in your web.config file.

Comment: Could you also provide an example in your answer of a rewrite rule that redirects /Home/* to /* (except for existing routes defined in RouteConfig)?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample rewrite rule which you can use. FYI.. You also need to install `URL Rewrite` in your IIS as well.