# Media query for img src attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

How to change image in mobile view for `img` `-->` `src` ? I want to change to different image in mobile view using media query how to do that? *I don't want to use it as background image!*

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
            <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of 
                the CSS class names have completely changed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to use js or jquery $("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");

Comment: why do you want to change the image? Do you want it to become smaller or should mobile users see a complete different image?

Comment: You can checkout under this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: @hansTheFranz i want the mobile user to see a smaller image of this or a new image to appear

Comment: @krychuq but i want to b able to use it in media query

Comment: in this case I would suggest to look into responsive design. Changing the image is not the correct use case for that but it would also work. look at this example. you can make the window smaller and the image will change its width automatically https://jsfiddle.net/f0dzr5uh/

Comment: Don't need media query or js, you can use the srcset attribute : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#Example_3_Using_the_srcset_attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-mobile-image {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .img-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-mobile-image {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="mobile-imag-path" class="img-mobile-image">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
      <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following classes to switch to different images. Please adjust the break point as you prefer.

```
   .pc_img {
      display:none;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .sp_img {
        display: none;
      }
      .pc_img {
        display: inline;
      }
    }
```