# How to show Images on json jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

**`PHP CODE:`**

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

**JQUERY AJAX:**

```
$(".comment").click(function(){
    var id  =  $(this).data("id");
    var name = $("#username_"+id).val();

    if(name=='') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comments",
            data:{comments:name,parent:id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                json.forEach(function (item, index){
                    var br = "<br>";
                    var url = "http://localhost/projects/quotes/assets/uploads/avatar/";
                    $(".cmt_comments img").append(""+url+item.image+"");
                    $(".cmt_comments").append(item.comments,br);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

JSON ARRAY:

```
[{"image":"1510553363_User_Avatar_2.png","comments":"NICE"}]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cmt_comments">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

http://localhost/projects/quotes/assets/uploads/avatar/1510553363_User_Avatar_2.pnghttp://localhost/projects/quotes/assets/uploads/avatar/1510553363_User_Avatar_2.png

NICE

**I want:**

```
Now display only image url. how to i display image
```

Comment: try this: $(".cmt_comments img").attr("src", url+item.image);

Comment: Okay.I will Try This

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: try this:  jQuery(".cmt_comments").append('<img src=""+url+item.image+"" />');