# Jquery click function with image src

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have an image which is as below

```
 <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" />
```

And I'm changing this img src alternatively by using the below code

```
1. $("[src*=plus]").click( function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
                });
2.  $("[src*=minus]").click(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            });
```

The first function is working as expected- when I click on the button for the first time the image is changing to 'minus',but when I click on this changed  'minus' image  the function call is going again to the same first function.
What am I doing wrong here.
Please help.

Referred  following link [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't wrong, just need to use `on` function, because you changing `src` after `DOM` in result it can't find new `src`, so you need to use live click function:

```
$(document).on('click','[src*=plus]',function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
});
$(document).on('click','[src*=minus]',function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click','[src*=plus]',function(){
  $(this).prop("src","images/minus.png");
  console.log('changed to minus');
});

$(document).on('click','[src*=minus]',function(){
  $(this).prop("src","images/plus.png");
  console.log('changed to plus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="some text" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `on()` instead of `click()` or use another attribute like `class` for check the current status of the image which is much lighter and easy to execute with a single click event.

```
$("[src*=plus]").on("click",function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
                });
$("[src*=minus]").on("click",function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
                });
```

or you can use the following as 
**HTML:**

```
<img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" onclick="javascript:return img_click(this);"/>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function img_click(el)
{
 if($(el).attr("src").toLowerCase().indexOf('plus') != -1)
 {
   $(el).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
 }
 else
 {
   $(el).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
 }

}
```

Comment: no error it is always going to the first function.Even when I click on the minus button.

Comment: so you can use the added code and function instead of the following code.

Comment: That works fine.Thanks ,but I'm really eager to know what is wrong with the code!

Comment: Some time according to your code the dynamic event not bound to elem due to your code.

Comment: When I added the 'on' also it behaves the same.

Comment: @Sribin why you don't try next answer? it solved your problem already.

Comment: It's same as you assign a function to an element at event fired so this behave as same as above.

Comment: @pedram :P what you wanna try to say there is my answer is not relevant or correct to use.Please if you find something wrong than share it there.

Comment: @pedram may be this depends, buddy not to force some to do what you want.that ans is updated when he says that not work with `on` may that's why he does not use your code.

Comment: @Sribin I mentioned to my answer. not this. scroll down to see next answer. it's simple! if you don't want to solve your problem, okay, it's up to you..

Comment: Happy to help @Sribin, and welcome to vote this one. If this answer or **any other one** solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks both of you for you effort.Both answers works fine.

Comment: then you have to choose one as you answer bro If this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '[src*=plus]', function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "https://png.icons8.com/color/100/minus");
});
$(document).on('click', '[src*=minus]', function() {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "https://png.icons8.com/color/100/plus");
});
```

The img with `src*=minus` doesn't exist initially when the event handlers are attached, hence we need to use `$(document).on('click', 'selector', handler)` thereby attaching handlers on the document.

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wrfscfw1/1/