# Changing the source of an image tag on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked a few times, but the answers are with onclick events - is it possible to change and image's src tag on page refresh with a predetermined/random source/package of image links?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: Sure it's possible.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Isn't that an onclick event? - is there an onrestart command alternative?

Comment: Hi David, well - basically on Tim Weber's link, on an onclick event changing rather than a on page refresh alternative.

Comment: Yes.  Have list of image source urls in your code and set one randomly when the script runs.  The script will run every time the page loads/refreshes.  What have you tried?

Comment: @RutherMelchor: There is no "on page refresh" event.  There also doesn't need to be.  Anything that happens when the code loads (such as in a document.ready event) happens on the page refresh.  Basically, if you want something to happen when the page loads, just write that code on the page.  It'll execute every time the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why StackOverflow turned out to be like this: filled with reputation-greedy people with ego's so high, the site turns to be 'un-helpful'.

Some tabbed this post as duplicate, even if I specifically said that the other one was on click, and I was asking about an on load version and how to execute.

Anyways, here's the solution that I've came with, no frills, no ego, just an answer that will help anyone out there that came to StackOverflow for help:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function loadImage(){

        var myArray = ["http://link1.gif, http://link2.gif"]; 
        var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

        document.getElementById("imgCon").src= rand.toString();

    }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="loadImage();">

<a href="#"><img id="imgCon"></a>

</body>
```