# Replacing image src with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML class where I want to replace the img src with different image. Have been able to find something close but nothing quite working.

HTML:

```
<div class="playoff-img">
  <a href=""><img src="src/img/imga.png"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('div.playoff-img:contains("src/img/imga.png")').replaceWith('src/new/image/imgb.png');
```

Comment: The question is duplicate of [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an attribute selector and use `.attr` to set the `src` attribute.

```
$('div.playoff-img img[src="src/img/imga.png"]').attr('src', 'src/new/image/imgb.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Js way of solving this problem**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src","http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg");
```

**The jQuery way of solving this problem**

```
$(".playoff-img img").attr("src", "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and easy !

```
$(".playoff-img img").attr("src", "put new source address here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attr*="value"]` to select an attribute that contains a particular string. Next you will want to use `attr()` to set the attribute to something new.

```
$('div.playoff-img img[src*="src/img/imga.png"]')
    .attr('src', 'src/new/image/imgb.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- use jquery -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="playoff-img">
  <a href=""><img src="src/img/imga.png"></a>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".playoff-img").attr("src", "put new source address here");
});
</script>
```