# Changing the image source using jQuery + FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented this code successfully in order toggle between img srcs using jquery, found from a previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery).

```
$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img1_on.jpg')
            ? 'img2_on.jpg'
            : 'img1_on.jpg';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

I was wondering if someone could help me to implement a fadeOut effect to transition between the img srcs, I've tried a handful of times and can't seem to wrap my head around jquery. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Take a look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ . You will find a lot more than fadeout, and is super easy to implement.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) and [`.fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) can take a second paramater to use as  a function when their animation is complete - You can use this to update the src only once the image is hidden

You can then chain `.fadeIn()` as normal afterwards

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
  let src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'https://placekitten.com/125/?image=11')
    ? 'https://placekitten.com/125/?image=12'
    : 'https://placekitten.com/125/?image=11';
    
  $(this)
    .fadeOut(1500, () => $(this).attr('src', src))
    .fadeIn(1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src='https://placekitten.com/125/?image=11'/>
```

I've swapped around your code slightly for the demo / clarity

Comment: you beat me to it!

Comment: hi, I was wondering if fadeOut and fadeIn is compatible to fade seamlessly like an overlay of the images - much like the solution offered just below. thank you!

Comment: how would I add a few more images to the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more of a transition between pictures rather than a full fade out and then full fade in, you can do this by using the background-image css property and css transitions:

```js
$(function() {
  var img1 = 'url("https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300")';
  var img2 = 'url("https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300")'

  $("#theImage").on('click', function(){
    var src = ($(this).css('background-image') === img1)
        ? img2
        : img1;   
    $(this).css('background-image', src) 
  });
});
```

```css
#theImage{
   display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300");
    -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 1200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1200ms ease-in;
    transition: all 1200ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="theImage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the hide() function before adding fadeIn() or fadeOut() effect. Thus, You will get your transition effect.

```
$('img').on({
     'click': function() {
        var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img1_on.jpg')
           ? 'img2_on.jpg'
           : 'img1_on.jpg';

     $(this).hide();
     $(this).attr("src",src).fadeIn("slow");
    }
 });
```