# Having a strange issue changing IMG src

Tags: javascript

So I am having a strange issue with JavaScript where one thing works and the other doesn't.

```
<img id="img_1" src="#" />
<img id="img_2" src="#" />
```

Example code:

```
  function changeName(id, name) {
    var image = name.files;

    $('#image_' + id).attr('data-title', image[0].name); // this works 
    $('#img_' + id).src = URL.createObjectURL(image[0]); // this doesn't
  }
```

This is what I tried and it works, but this obviously doesn't work for multiple IMG fields:

```
img_1.src = URL.createObjectURL(image[0]); // seems to work just fine
```

What am I trying to accomplish?

So the idea is that you get to preview the image before you upload it to the server. I have multiple upload fields so there will be multiple parts where you get to preview the image (it's for a blog).

I feel really dumb for asking why this doesn't work. Is this just a stupid brainfart or am I missing something?

Any idea? your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: Have you tried `.attr('src', ...)` ?